# shell - assigning variable from file to other variable?

Tags: shell

I'm trying to understand what '=' and '>' operators do in below code. I only know that sh_filename_load is separate sh script. Do you have any ideas?

`begin`

`sh_filename_load.rate_change (previous_date => '$(PREVIOS_DAY)', mail_list => '$(mail_list)');`

`end;`

Comment: Where did you copy this from?

Comment: It's from shell script which is run in putty. Part of shell script is SQLplus

Comment: This doesn't look like POSIX shell syntax, copying and pasting this to sh results in syntax errors. You better double-check which program interprets this code, and add its tag to your question.

Comment: @marti : If you had bothered to actually run this script via some Posix-like shell (dash, ash, ....), you would have seen from the error message, that this is not a shell script.  Even if you had executable files with names _begin_ and _end_ in your PATH, the usage of parenthesis and `>` in the middle command are simply incorrect. At least you should specify **how** you run the script. I also suggest that you paste your scripts into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to do some basic checks on them.